# Using webpack to get all paths in directory

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some front end code which needs to run for each png in a specific directory. I am using Webpack but am unsure of how use it for this.

I realize that Webpack only runs server-side, but that's fine. What I'm looking for is a variable which is an array of paths. I don't want to hard-code it because there are a lot of png files.

Ideally, there is some sort of general-purpose compile time command I can use to interpolate Javascript into the result, something like this:

```
var glob = require("glob")
var loadFiles = new Promise(funtion(resolve, reject) { 
  CompileTimeCommand(function() {
    glob("assets/tilesheet_images/*.png", function (er, paths) {
      if (err) { reject(err) } else { resolve(paths) }
    })
  })
})
loadFiles.then(function(paths) {
  // etc
})
```

The problem is, this `CompileTimeCommand` doesn't exist.

Is there a way I can do this with `require`, or some sort of general purpose compile-time macro system? I have written a Webpack loader before, but it seems overkill to have to make a new package for a simple, ad-hoc command.

Is there a better way than to just make a separate script which runs the dir glob and saves the paths into a json file which is read by my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a list of files at run-time and it can change at run-time then you'd rather use your back-end technology to access file system and return results to front-end via http call for example.
Otherwise if files are static and are determined at compile time then you can use `glob` in webpack config file and put its results into [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to replace some variable with a list of files.

Comment: i see ... so i can run node code in the webpack file and use defineplugin to make globals. Thanks!